# paginated Laravel table sorted by relation's attribute

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent, laravel-pagination, laravel-relations

Let's say I have such a structure:

cities:

- id
- name
- belongsTo(countries)

countries:

- id
- name

How can I get a paginated list of cities, ordered by country name?

How I see it:

```
$res = City::query()->join('countries', 'country_id', '=', 'countries.id')->orderBy('countries.name')->paginate($records_per_page, ['*'], 'page', $page_number);
```

or

```
$res = City::query()->with('country')->orderBy('country.name')->paginate($records_per_page, ['*'], 'page', $page_number);
```

Also I have seen solutions with sorting collections after getting the query result, but I think it is worse when paginating.

What is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve your problem.

I assume your belongs to column to country is country_id in cities table:

```
$res = City::query()->select("*",
            \DB::raw('(SELECT name FROM countries WHERE countries.id = cities.country_id) as countryname'))
            ->orderBy('countryname', 'DESC')
            ->paginate($records_per_page, ['*'], 'page', $page_number);
```